# What is the 'undo' command in base-level shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I'm trying to convert an old installation script to Dockerfile and keep coming across syntax like this:

```
  # unpack the tar
  reportandprint "..Unpacking archive\n"
  suWrap "tar xf $DISTDIR/$ISTAR"
  undo "rm -rf $INSROOT/$ISDIR/*"

  # make /var and /etc trees
  reportandprint "..Creating cache directory\n"
  reportcmdandeval "mv $INSROOT/$ISDIR/var $VARROOT/$ISDIR"
  undo "rm -rf $VARROOT/$ISDIR"
  suWrap "ln -s $VARROOT/$ISDIR $INSROOT/$ISDIR/var"
  suWrap "mkdir $INSROOT/$ISDIR/var/catalogs"
  undo "rm -f $INSROOT/$ISDIR/var"
```

Can someone explain the to me the usage of the command 'undo' here? Is this a fallback if the previous line fails to execute? This doesn't seem to be common usage and all I've been able to come up with searching online so far is a lot of people looking to 'undo' something they've inadvertently done in shell :)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `undo` is not a standard command. It's probably a function defined in your specific project.

Comment: None of those commands are standard Linux commands. Check the rest of the script to see if they're defined as functions.

Comment: These commands are not just nonstandard, they're also defined in a way that makes them bug-prone. Competent people would accept argument lists as arrays, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely they're helper functions in the script. Look at how they are defined in it.

My guess is
`undo` keeps a tally of commands to undo the scripts progress so far (probably activated with a `trap` on INT/EXIT).

`suWrap` would run the line as superuser, and `reportandprint` would prefix and format text output.

Helper functions are useful to make your script shorter and easier to read. For example. Say you want to stop your script and print an error message on stderr (2). 
You could go: `echo "Error: this error" >&2; exit 1` every time.
But it's better to define a function that does that for you and use it throughout the script.

```
errexit() {
  printf "Error:\t %s\n" "$@" >&2
  exit 1
}
 
errexit "this error"
errexit "that error"
```

It looks like `reportandprint` and the other commands are used this way but you have to find where the functions are defined to find out.